# Status Flags when comparing two values

Tags: assembly

I am very confused when it comes to status flags. Can someone help me through an example and the steps I need to take to verify how the flags are behaving?

`mov ah, 21`
`mov al, -21`
`cmp ah,al`

Can someone help me determine the behavior of the CF, ZF,SF, and OF?

Thanks

Comment: There's an app - erm - manual for that.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423548/68000-assembly-language-cmpi-b/26425658). While that is for 68k, the logic for the 4 flags (with `N`=`SF` and `V`=`OF`) is the same on x86 too except here the second operand is subtracted from the first.

Comment: [`cmp` is just `sub`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261535/why-does-cmp-0x84-0x30-trigger-the-overflow-flag), except that its operands are not affected, just the flags register.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `eflags` register in a debugger (like gdb).  There is plenty of readily accessible documentation about [eflags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register), but essentially bits in the register are 0 or 1 depending on whether particular status flags are set.

If it is not enough to just see the values in a debugger, and you need to do something with them:

1. you can push `eflags` onto the stack (`pushfl` works for me) and then pop the stack to a general purpose register.
2. You can use the `jc`, `jz`, `jo`, and `js` instructions which jump to a specified label if the carry, zero, overflow, or sign flags (respectively) are set.

For example:

```
    clc                     # clear carry flag (set CF = 0)
    addl eax, 0xffffffff    # some operation that might change status flags
    jc label1               # if the carry flag is set, jump to label

    ...                     # instructions to execute if carry not set (CF = 0)

    jmp label2

label1:

    ...                     # instructions to execute if carry set (CF = 0)

label2:

    ...                     # resume execution which does not depend on CF
```